# how to hide string in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

In the view have a string, that shows from a database string with the website address.
How to make so that would absence of this website address in the database, the string will not be displaying the view?

**website:**
<%= link_to @restaurant.site, url_with_protocol(@restaurant.site) >

in the absence website address remains the first string, and I wish that it only appears when there address

PS

That this could be done, as in writing this code:

<% if session[:user_id] %> <% end >

which displays information only if the user is registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it the same way.

```
<% if @restaurant.site %>
  <%= link_to @restaurant.site, url_with_protocol(@restaurant.site) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: link_to_if if its there in RoR 3. Seen it in Rails 2.

Comment: I think it still leaves the text, doesn't it ?